# Lipid Diffusion

Tags: cell-membrane, membrane-transport

Epithelial cells in the small intestine absorb lipids through simple diffusion but how does diffusion of lipids occur in the first place if they are insoluble in water? I thought that substances need to be dissolved in order to have concentration and therefore a concentration gradient?

Comment: Insolubility means they don't dissolve in water and may self-associate. That doesn't mean they cannot exist in aqueous environments. I'm not sure this question is clear enough to answer accurately.

Comment: Do you actually have a reference that supports your understanding as being correct?

Comment: http://www.vivo.colostate.edu/hbooks/pathphys/digestion/smallgut/absorb_lipids.html     "The major products of lipid digestion - fatty acids and 2-monoglycerides - enter the enterocyte by simple diffusion across the plasma membrane. A considerable fraction of the fatty acids also enter the enterocyte via a specific fatty acid transporter protein in the membrane." Essentially I would like to know if a non-soluble substance could diffuse in water because my current understanding is that only dissolved substances can.